# Hiding buttons in angular js based on a state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am developing an application in angular js and using ui.router.
I would like to hide certain buttons based on a given state.

I have implementend the click event which navigates to the selected state, and i would like when a button has been clicked and is active to be hidden and reappear when the state is not active

I have tried

```
HTML FOR THE BUTTONS
<button type="button" ng-click="viewNew()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
        </i> New calls
    </button>
    <button type="checkbox" ng-click="viewAssigned()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
        </i> Assigned calls
    </button>
```

On the controller

```
    $scope.viewAssigned = function () {

    $state.go("dash.call.assigned");
   }

$scope.viewNew = function () {

    $state.go("dash.call.new");
      }
```

How can i alter my controller code to hide and show these buttons using ng-show

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add information about the state to the controller, through something like `$scope.state = $state.current.name` 
From there, you can use that in an ng-show or ng-if.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
<button type="checkbox" ng-click="viewAssigned()" ng-hide="$state.includes('dash.call.assigned')" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Assigned calls
</button>
```

you should have added $state in $rootScope, for this to work.
Inject $state, $rootScope and place this in your app's run block.

```
$rootScope.$state = $state;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a $scope variable to track the state change.look at the below code

```
    $scope.viewAssigned = function () {
     $scope.viewnew = true;
    $state.go("dash.call.assigned");
   }

$scope.viewNew = function () {
     $scope.viewnew = false;
    $state.go("dash.call.new");
      }
```

And your HTML code should be like this,

```
<button type="button" ng-click="viewNew()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-hide="viewnew">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
    </i> New calls
</button>
<button type="checkbox" ng-click="viewAssigned()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-hide="!viewnew">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
    </i> Assigned calls
</button>
```

Comment: It doesnt work the button with ng-click="viewAssigned()" is hidden forever even when i navigate via the browser manually to the next state... The functions view assigned and viewNew are click events..

Comment: why the second button has type="checkbox"?

Answer (score 0):

You can see when the `$state` is changing and hide that buttons. On your `run()` you can use a function similar to this:

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.viewnew= false;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (toState.name === 'myState') {//toState variable see the state you're going 
            $rootScope.viewnew = false;
        } else {
            $rootScope.viewnew = true;
        }
    });
});
```

then add this to your buttons:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="viewNew()" ng-hide="viewnew" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
        </i> New calls
    </button>
    <button type="checkbox" ng-click="viewAssigned()" ng-hide="!viewnew" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
        </i> Assigned calls
    </button>
```

so when your `$state` change it would hide or show it.